# Interface IOCTL in winsock2: Help needed

Tags: sockets, network-programming, tunneling

So apparently the Winsock2 equivalents of `ioctl()`, which are `ioctlsocket()` and `WSAIoctl()`, do not accept the `ifreq` structure as a parameter or have a clear option for attaching a socket to an interface. I am writing a p2p IM program that uses ISATAP tunneling. I used netsh to enable the ISATAP tunnel interface but not sure how to issue a command to `WSAIoctl()` to set the sockets to the IPv6 ISATAP Tunnel interface.

Comment: Which `ioctl()` operation(s) are you trying to port to WinSock exactly? Chances are that WinSock may have its own equivalents of them.

Comment: I'm trying to port SIOCADDTUNNEL. I used the ipconfig command on the Win8 powershell and enabled the isatap adapter interface but I am not sure how to associate the socket with that specific interface.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget that WinSock sockets are bindable to specific interfaces via `bind()`, and are also configurable via `setsockopt()`.  For instance, there is an `ip_mreq` structure (defined for the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` and `IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP` socket options), and an `ip_mreq_source` structure (defined for the `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP`, `IP_DROP_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP`, `IP_BLOCK_SOURCE`, and `IP_UNBLOCK_SOURCE` socket options), which contain interface-related fields.

Comment: The bind() function binds a socket to an IP address. In Linux sockets, the setsockopt() and ioctl() can be used to associate a socket with a specific Adapter network interface. Windows seems to make this process MUCH trickier.

Comment: WinSock doesn't distinquish between adapters and IP addresses as much as other platforms do. Since an adapter is assigned an IP anyway, binding a socket to an IP also binds it to the adapter that the IP is assigned to. However, there are APIs for getting adapter interface information, and some socket operations, like multicasting, do make use of adapter interfaces.